# Return elements of list as individual items in Python

Tags: python, list, return

Hi people of Stackoverflow,

I have a function which calculates a list and I want to return each element of the list individually, like so (the function receiving this return is designed to handle an undefined number of parameters):

```
def foo():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4]
    return 1,2,3,4
```

The number of elements in the list is undefined so I can't do:

```
return my_list[0], my_list[1], ...
```

I think there must be an easy solution to this but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for your answers, so here is the extension to my problem, which is really my problem:

```
def foo():
    my_list = [1,2,3,4]
    return "any_other_value", my_list
```

So, what I want is that when I call `foo()`, `bar = foo()`, `bar[0] = "any_other_value", bar[1] = 1, bar[2]=3, bar[3] = 4`. And `my_list` is of undetermined length (here it has only 4 elements).

Comment: What are you trying to do? Functions will always return a single value, `1,2,3,4` is just a tuple and you might as well `return my_list` directly.

Comment: How will you catch these outputed individual elements. Would yield serve your purpose?

Comment: Hi! I expanded my question to my actual problem. Thanks. @Abhishek yes, maybe `yield` would work, but sincerely I am not very familiar with iterables and yield's and these parts of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. Just do what you were doing as (I suppose you could convert it to how you are showing it with `tuple(my_list)` but it is unnecessary):

```
return my_list
```

This is all you need to do because when you call that function that takes an undefined number of parameters, you can just call it as such:

```
function_with_undefined_number_of_params(*foo())
```

The `*` unpacks the returned `list` into separate arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but, and correct me if I am wrong, this would return a single tuple with all the elements inside, so if I do bar = foo(), bar would contain all the elments inside a tuple. And I need bar[0]=1, bar[1]=2 and so on. Hope I am clear, though.

Comment: No wait, you are right. I'll recheck and see if this is solves my little problem here.

Comment: @user11291 Great, I'm glad I could help. If I have resolved your issue, feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I am confused, the fucntion that returns my_list is foo() or function_with_undefined_number_of_params?