# Return multiple values from *args in python

Tags: python, controls, generator

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261392/returning-every-element-from-a-list-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381739/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-args) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030007/return-elements-of-list-as-individual-items-in-python), but I'm still confused and unsure where/how to use generators/`yield` and splat/`*`.

Use case: Sanitize inputs before further manipulating them.

```
def sanitize_inputs(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if arg == '':
            yield None
        else:
            yield arg

"{}|{}".format(sanitize_inputs('abc',''))
```

Ideally, `sanitize_inputs` should return an expanded list so the string substitution will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after this was siting in draft state, figured it out, thanks to [this](http://pynash.org/2013/03/13/unpacking/)

```
In: "{}|{}".format(*sanitize_inputs('abc',''))
Out: 'abc|None'
```